# JavaScript function/event listener not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, function, events, event-handling, addeventlistener

I'm completely new to JavaScript, and don't know why this isn't working. When I click on the input box, and type in less than 5 characters, i want a message to display. The message is simply not showing. Source code: https://jsfiddle.net/015por64/

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <form id="form>">
        <input id="input">
        <div id="text"> Test </div>
        </input>
        </form>   
    </body>
</html>

<script>
function checkUserName(e, minLength) {
  var username = document.getElementById("input");
  var usernameLength = username.textContent;
    if (usernameLength.value.length < 5) {
        msg = "Your username must consist of at least five characters."
    };
    else {
        msg = "";
        text.innerHTML=msg
    };
}
var text = document.getElementById("text");
text.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {checkUserName(e, 5)}, false)
</script>
```

Comment: For `input` elements you should read the `value` property instead of `textContent`. Also note that `input` is a void element and it doesn't have an ending tag.

Comment: Thanks, but even when I change textContent to value, it doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you listening to `blur` event of the `div` element? You should listen to `keyup` event of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues with your code:

1. you need to attach the event to `#input` and not the `div#text`.
2. you need to read value of `#input` and not `textcontent`
3. `;` after if is wrong because then else will give syntax error.

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <form id="form>">
        <input id="input">
        <div id="text"> Test </div>
        </input>
        </form>   
    </body>
</html>

<script>
function checkUserName(e, minLength) {
  var username = document.getElementById("input");
  var usernameLength = username.value;
    if (usernameLength.length < 5) {
        msg = "Your username must consist of at least five characters.";
        text.innerHTML=msg;
    }else {
        msg = "";
        text.innerHTML=msg;
    };
}
var text = document.getElementById("text");
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener("blur", function(e) {checkUserName(e, 5);}, false)
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! Apparantly, I can't accept the answer in for 7 minutes, but I will once i can. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be the input where you have to put the *blur* event listener.

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
```

And since you have no use for `text` outside the function, better define it inside.